# Hide all the child elements of div( text field , select , checkbox, radio) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have few form elements and a radio button in my jsp page and few other form elements( text field , text area , select , checkbox etc) in a div tag. Now My requirement is to hide all the child elements of the div when I select one of the radio button which is out side the div tag.

Here is my jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="tags" uri="/struts-tags"%>
 <html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
 <tags:form name="someForm" action="someAction" method="post">
 <tags:textfield key="someActionClass.transactionDate" id="datepicker" label="Transaction Date" />
 <tags:radio list="#{'1':'One Time','2':'Recurring'}" id="tType" lable="Transaction Type" name="recurringOrOneTime"></tags:radio>


 <div class="hideTesting">
  <tags:textfield name="testingFiled" lable="testing"/>
  <tags:textfield name="testingFiled1" lable="testing"/>
 <tags:textfield name="testingFiled2" lable="testing"/>
 </div>
 <script src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>

  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
   });

   $("input[name='recurringOrOneTime']").change(function(){
   var checkedVal=$(this).val();
   if(checkedVal=='1')
   {
      $("input[name='testingFiled']").toggle();
      $("input[name='testingFiled']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else
    {
    $("input[name='testingFiled']").toggle();
    $("input[name='testingFiled']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
   });
   </script>
  </tags:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

By using the above code I am able to hide the element but I need to use the element name to hide/show it. What I want to do is to hide all the child elements of div tag irrespective of it's name or type. can some one suggest a simple code for this.

below are the list of codes that I have tried to achieve the above mentioned issues but no luck.

```
  Try1=>$("div").filter(":hidden").children("input[type='text']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     Try2=>$("input,select,textarea", $(".hideTesting")).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    Try3=>$("input,select,textarea", $(".hideTesting")).toggle();
    Try4=> $("input",$(".hideTesting")).toggle();
    Try5=>$(".hideTesting").children("input[type='text']").toggle();

    Try6=>$("div.testingFiled").find('input').toggle();
```

Comment: Reason to just not use `$(".hideTesting").hide();`? `hide all the child elements of the div` so why not hiding the DIV instead?

Comment: `$('divid').children().hide()`?

Comment: for testing purpose I have placed a plain text in div tag.I have used the same $(".hideTesting").hide(); for hiding but It is not hiding the elements. It is just hiding the plain text which is there in the div tag.  I am not sure the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$("#tType").click(function () {
  $(".hideTesting").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give this way:

```
$("input:radio").click(function () {
  $(".hideTesting").hide();
});
```

Comment: Ya seems logic after all :)

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't understand why the OP wanna complicate things. Maybe a newbie?

Comment: But maybe OP has some specific style applied to DIV like setting size he wants to keep, but who knows?!

Comment: @A. Wolff 
 I am sorry. But I have tried the above code but it is not working. I have placed a plain text and a text box inside the div tag and used the above code. it is just hiding the plain text and not hiding the text box

Comment: @GhostRider Replicate issue where it can be checked because what you said isn't possible

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: same issue. I have replaced my code with your and it is hiding the plain text as I mentioned in my previous comments and point to be noted is the operation should be done with change in state of the radio button not when I click on one of the radio button.

Comment: @GhostRider **Show the code that uses my solution?**